# Wordpress fixed header disappears on mobile scroll

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a unique problem which I hope someone can help fix.

I have tweaked my WordPress header on CSS, canceling the background color, so that the background image can be seen instead (it is a white .png image with transparency at the bottom edge so that there is a pattern rather than a straight line at its bottom border).
see http://m.piccolo.co.il or https://piccolo.co.il (2 different websites).

the header's background-image has position: fixed (#masthead)

This works fine when you scroll down on a browser such as Chrome, or Explorer. However, when I scroll on IOS mobile, at some point the header's background-image disappears, leaving only the toggle bar and logo fixed.
[screenshot from IOS10 - Iphone SE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJWRg.png)

This is the header's CSS:

```
    #ht-masthead{
        background-image: url('http://www.piccolo.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/ht-mast.gif'); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100px;
        background-attachment: fixed !important;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
z-index: 99;
    transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translatez(0);
    -ms-transform: translatez(0);
    -o-transform: translatez(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; 
}
```

Any suggestions would be great, I am getting very frustrated with this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I managed a "patch solution" using the CSS after tag.
I gave #masthead:after these attributes forcing the torn pattered background there.

I applied it for now only to m.piccolo.co.il, like this:

```
#ht-masthead:after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
left: 0;
height: 100px;
right: 0;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-size: stretch;

background-image: url('http://m.piccolo.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/ht-mast2-1.png');
```

}

Any thoughts?
Thanks